# SQl Query: Count products in category, once product count in 1 category, do not count it in other category

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a product in different categories, 1 product may be in more than 1 categories. I want to get "which category has the most unique products"

Sample data:

```
Table: Category

Category_ID ||   NAME 
1           ||   clothes
2           ||   bags
3           ||   shirts


Tabale: category_joins {product + category ids only}
Product_ID ||   Category_ID
1          ||    1
5          ||    1

1          ||    3
2          ||    3  
3          ||    3
```

Count Which category has the most unique products?:

```
Result
Count     ||   Category_id
1         ||   1
3         ||   3

{Exclude Product_ID "1" from Category_ID "1", because it is in category "3",
and only count Product_ID 1 in Category 3 because Category 3 has most unique products}
```

Product id "1" in two categories

I want a total number of products in categories, 
but if product count in 1 category, do not count it in another category.

Help me to write its QUERY.

Comment: Why shouldn't we exclude product 1 from category 3 instead?

Comment: I need category 3 in result to work on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proirity of the category is based on the number of products, if equal on `Category_ID`. For each product take only top priority category.

```
select Product_ID, Category_ID
from (
    select  c1.Product_ID, c1.Category_ID, row_number() over (partition by Product_ID order by rnk) priority
    from category_joins c1
    join (
      select Category_ID, row_number() over (order by count(distinct Product_ID) desc, Category_ID) rnk
      from category_joins
      group by Category_ID
    ) cr on cr.Category_ID = c1.Category_ID
) t
where priority = 1
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9d64b964e5bb6821e4b91d084a551b79)

To get count of the uniquely distributed products by category

```
select Category_ID, count(*) n
from (
    select  c1.Product_ID, c1.Category_ID, row_number() over (partition by Product_ID order by rnk) priority
    from category_joins c1
    join (
      select Category_ID, row_number() over (order by count(distinct Product_ID) desc, Category_ID) rnk
      from category_joins
      group by Category_ID
    ) cr on cr.Category_ID = c1.Category_ID
) t
where priority = 1
group by Category_ID;
```